# Gallery View inside scroll view not working.

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-scrollview

I'm using gallery view inside scoll view but gallery view not working properly.

**My custom GalleryView**

```
<com.divum.Adapter.CustomGallery
android:id="@+id/gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:spacing="10dp" />
```

**Adapter Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/top_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100">
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/txt_title1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="14dp" />      
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/image1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />
<ScrollView 
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/txt_details"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="14dp" />      
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**My problem** is scrollview(vertically) working fine. The galleryview(horizontally) swiping  is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well known bug: `ScrollView` intercept both horizontal and vertical touch events. You can use this custom scroll view instead of standard one. This intercept only vertical touches:

```
public class VerticalScrollView extends ScrollView {

private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;

public VerticalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
        lastX = ev.getX();
        lastY = ev.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        final float curX = ev.getX();
        final float curY = ev.getY();
        xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
        yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
        lastX = curX;
        lastY = curY;
        if (xDistance > yDistance)
            return false;
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

}
```

Comment: I used this view with `ViewPager` and it start working. Did you try to move your custom gallery outside `ScrollView`?Do you sure it works?

Comment: no i want to scroll only textview. title and image i don't want to scoll.

Comment: Oh sorry, i meen your Gallery works without `ScrollView` insideof it?

Comment: oh it's ok. u have any idea for this??

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand your question, this solution works or not?

Comment: @Evos How to use this custom scroll view in code? I have declared normal scrollview in xml file and it starts working by default. But how to make this custom scrollview work? Please suggest.

Comment: @Korhan write full class path to your custom sroll view instead of plain `<ScrollView` as your opening and closing tags, like this `<com.divum.views.VerticalScrollView`

Comment: @Evos Yeah. I have done this already, but it's not working. Do you have any other suggestions?