# Gallery View is not working inside scrollview

Tags: android, gallery, scrollview

I have a lots of data to be displayed on one `Activity`. So, I just used `ScrollView`. But the thing is I have even 5-6 images to be displayed on the same activity.

So, I used `GalleryView` inside `ScrollView` and it exactly suits my requirement. Because in gallery, 5-6 images are kept and it acts as a preview container and whenever user clicks on gallery item, I show the respective image on the `ImageView` which acts as an enlarged image. This works fine on some devices, but when I tested on ICS devices, the `ScrollView` is not visible at all and it doesn't work. Finally the gallery view is not shown up at all.

As I have shown in the below figure it just works fine in some devices, but in some devices (**ICS**) gallery and image in the `ImageView` do not show up at all. Can some one please help me? I would be very thankful. If some one can suggest me alternative to achieve same kind of feature that gallery provides, it is most welcome as I too know that scrolling things cannot be working in another scrolling thing all the times. Have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233310/gallery-view-inside-scroll-view-not-working) and some other but nothing worked.

[image: Image of activity and highlighted which part doesn't work on some devices]